# Flatten type with const assertion using recursion

Tags: typescript, recursion

I have the following TypeScript code:

```js
type Item = {
    key: number;
    value: string;
    items?: readonly Item[];
}

const items = [
    { key: 1, value: 'foo', items: [{ key: 3, value: 'baz' }] },
    { key: 2, value: 'bar' }
] as const;

type MyItem = typeof items[number]; // how to make this flatten?

function getItemValue<K extends MyItem['key']>(key: K): Extract<MyItem, { key: K }>['value'];
function getItemValue(key: MyItem['key']) {
    return ''; // implementation details are not relevant.
}

const x = getItemValue(1);
//    ^? const x: "foo"

const y = getItemValue(2);
//    ^? const x: "bar"

const z = getItemValue(3); // to make this work (it should return 'baz')
//    ^?
```

The function `getItemValue` should return the `value` of the item with the given `key`.
It should only allow valid `keys` and return the correct corresponding value type based on the `items` array.

I'm only interested in the typings. The implementation of the function is not relevant. I made it work for the main, but not the nested items.

Is there a way to flatten the `MyItem` type?

Here the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8CwAoKuoGsIQAuKAOwFcEAjCAJwG5s8oA3AQwBsKJSBnYHQCWZAOZMceIfAR8A-KToR2AEwD2ZTiFgyA2gF0JAX2zYAxhoFRpiPiii7meNASKkAjABo2XHqQDkAGZqav7eNrKkui6EJFAAzN4c3LxQ-tTsAF7%20UEb6uZ5OuDFuUABMSb6p6ex0OSZY%20ex2FmQCEtigkFAAsiBwiPZdEGqB1jJ8upQ09IZQAPTzUAAWagDuUMBqUAjshJvLQnaBnOzA8GRypliBFGRmwEIaUKIQwAMIAGpVADwA0lAIAAPC4qOx9D66fyxfz6AB8AApYqQ-gBKUgAURBdHYDx%20EJk3hKcQBRjhUOSPFhElu90ez1e7xk3xSSNKBMQUJh%20lR6CKUCUwAodDIaX8DAWSyECDAnEQEDIwDOT1FKje7CEnDstWgfAgrRUtRAADpsA1zJZgFAgfZGR8WTwEe5URJFiwAHpXLAWtpW7SoO3MqoIsou7BuvCe66tKyZW1ve3B%20IuyWbba7fbAQ52NZqOj4KAI6RQPirCicFQCt7C0U1bKo8NLSNyIA)

Comment: Are you asking about the *typings* or the *implementation*?  Both of them are not working in your example, and they're essentially separate questions due to the compiler's inability to verify the correctness of code with nested types like that.  Anyway [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mp0JMm) shows a version where both the typings and the implementation work, but I would love to be able to limit the scope of the question to just one of those so that any answer I give would be more focused.  How would you like to proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz: Thank you for your answer. I'm only asking about the typings. 
The implementation of the function is secondary.

Comment: Great, I'll write up an answer about the typings; could you [edit] to remove the implementation from your question, since it doesn't work and is therefore a distraction at best?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I removed the implementation details from the question and the playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to write a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) called, say, `ItemsToFlattenedUnion<T>` that takes a `readonly Item[]` input and produces a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the `Item` types at all levels of the tree structure.  It could look like this:

```
type ItemsToFlattenedUnion<T> =
    T extends readonly Item[] ? { [I in keyof T]:
        T[I] | (
            T[I] extends { items: infer I } ? ItemsToFlattenedUnion<I> : never
        ) }[number] :
    never
```

This works by [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) any input `Item` array  to another array type of `ItemsToFlattenedUnion<>` for each element, along with the current element, and then [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) this type with `number` to get all those in a single union.

You can test that on your `items`:

```
type FlattenedUnion = ItemsToFlattenedUnion<typeof items>;
/* type FlattenedUnion = {
    readonly key: 3;
    readonly value: "baz";
} | {
    readonly key: 1;
    readonly value: "foo";
    readonly items: readonly [{
        readonly key: 3;
        readonly value: "baz";
    }];
} | {
    readonly key: 2;
    readonly value: "bar";
} */
```

That's enough for you to use with your current [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)-based approach.  Still I think it's cleaner to collect that into a simpler key-value utility object type with [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
type FlattenItems<T extends readonly Item[]> =
    { [U in ItemsToFlattenedUnion<T> as U["key"]]: U["value"] }

type ItemKeyValues = FlattenItems<typeof items>;
/* type ItemKeyValues = {
    3: "baz";
    1: "foo";
    2: "bar";
} */
```

That is more succinct, and your `getItemValue()` call signature therefore be written as a single indexed access:

```
declare function getItemValue<K extends keyof ItemKeyValues>(
  key: K
): ItemKeyValues[K];
```

Let's test that out:

```
const x = getItemValue(1);
//    ^? const x: "foo"
const y = getItemValue(2);
//    ^? const y: "bar"
const z = getItemValue(3); 
//    ^? const z: "baz"
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8CwAoKuoGsIQAuKAOwFcEAjCAJwG5s8oA3AQwBsKJSBnYHQCWZAOZMceIfAR8A-KToR2AEwD2ZTiFgyA2gF0JAX2zYAxhoFRpiPiii7meNASKkAjABo2XHqQDkAGZqav7eNrKkui6EJFAAzN4c3LxQ-tTsAF7+UEb6uZ5OuDFuUABMSb6p6ex0OSZY+ex2FmQCEqZY2KCQOrYAKmoAYpzswPBkECoAqmRCGgA8-QB8KEVQ-VAQAB4TKnZKqhpafQgGUHLoDjDWZK4gaoEb+sTrLP26MPkAPlAAFG8WHgPl8trsIGR9lcInxSCJAvRYLkLqc+IMRmMJlNZvMyAsYKtSJNWPRAbgAJS5XSUGj0fKvSS4YmkrpYHrQDHjCHYuYaexwAbDUZcyYzXl49mPawyPjLCQAegAVFB2VBOVixbj7JhGVBDupNNpYqR4hIWPrjtpkn4oAAiDKZW3GKC-HXm5QGk7GqDuM14C2GnwpUi24JqJ3rAMnGGKD2WhxuoG4KNG0qmsl6uOB62pe1ZCO6vLO12RrNe0plP3JstWqohjJ0AtGKCK+WdVXqiEC2RLMF7A4104GVbIdYuXTTW6o9HCjU4xYrKDNKDTXS22K2-QvFdrnOb3Lt8DQbsAaSIADUqnZUJ2yN2+AtJU8YXLsEqVUfTmeQJeUtf0Os8T1vmVY+iGYYFiwZTAY2zqtp0gQUGQZjAFqogQMA3a-jwCwnn2EJQrEUqnheV7LH83onuSpAkT+V66CehjYIhyGoXy6GYTI2EQBRpREU8tHcXwlKJrgLEoWhGF-DGmZHIG3YGNRpwulASEqBAgQiFMAG6iwnAYVAwRqfYMIAHSaZC0koKsQimbEKDIKgsTkqBLBCE8fxGZClJKMAFB0HcXkqK5eDBHQ-ytFYQhQFKMIiRmbkeQAhLZcVQK0qGUBAIVJkF9gcdJplxTlQLuf8QU+Rh-mBWoaklQ0SbVn5AWqZCGlacF6wNf6VUtQVcVyKZObGJ05iWMAUDbPlGFYVUfzuC5b7yiwAB6chjW0aj6aZnBqKIfzbJS8rLaGIQFhtVjaKgHGzSkfxlItWDHat61YJFW0QDte1-CAR0nQ2tqdJFE2ZNNnGINxfzxC5UDPcAahQAg7CECqAAWQh2AA7modD4P80hQHwqO1ZwKiZs1dw1Nk5JLS9F0fV9+2ZH9doOoDrJAA)